# how to move a layer by dragging?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, calayer

How to move a layer by dragging after I added the CATextLayer to UIImageView Layer. As I will add more than one layer to UIImageView. So, How can I know which layer I clicked and move it to another position?

Here is my code for drawing text:

```
func addText() -> CATextLayer{
    let rect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 600, width: 120, height: 60)
    let myAttributes = [
                        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size:18)!,
                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black.cgColor
                        ] as [String : Any]
    let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "TEST STRING", attributes: myAttributes)

    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.frame = rect
    textLayer.string = myAttributedString
    textLayer.position = CGPoint(x:150,y:400)
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    return textLayer
}
```

Comment: I have solved the problem use of custom view and define the event handlers to control the dragging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer` and `hitTest()` are the way to go:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: ImageView!
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
var newLayer = CATextLayer()

// this is your code above, be careful, you want each layer "named"!
nextLayer = addText()

imageView.layer.addSubLayer(nextLayer)
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func moveLayer(_ recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
    if newLayer.hitTest(p) != nil {
        newLayer.position = p
    }
}
```

That's about it. My code is a skeleton where I'm assuming you want the layers inside the imageView. But they can be part of the superview if you want.

Again, be careful with how you set up the layers - you need to access them specifically if you have multiple ones to move around. My code was an attempt to use your function. Maybe you could store the layers in an array (if you don't know how many there will be) or as global variables to either the imageView or the view controller.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But if 2 layers are overlapped on the same location which layer will be moved?

Comment: Actually, I would like to implement the draw text function like this one https://youtu.be/qdtzZGn7NaM?t=14m2s there is a border shape around the text and user can drag, edit or delete it. Is it possible to solve the problem use of layer?