# UIPanGestureRecognizer handler crashes my applications - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an application that contains a `UIImageView`.  I have drawn a small circle in a subview of the parent `UIImageView`.  I would like the user to be able to touch and drag the small blue circle within the main UIImageView.  I have set up a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for this child view.  I am trying to test if my handler for the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is being fired, but as I touch and drag on the main `UIImageView`, my app crashes with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   firstDotHandlerWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x103507d80'

**Swift**:

```
var firstDotView: UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstDotView = UIView.init()
    firstDotView?.frame = imgView.bounds
    imgView.addSubview(firstDotView!)

    // DRAW A FILLED IN BLUE CIRCLE
    drawBlueCircle()

    imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    firstDotView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // ADD GESTURE RECOGNIZER
    let firstDotPanRecgnzr = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: firstDotView!, action: #selector(firstDotHandler(sender:)))
    firstDotView?.addGestureRecognizer(firstDotPanRecgnzr)
}


@objc func firstDotHandler(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void {

    print("translation ...")

    let firstDot = sender.view
    let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

    if(sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed){
        firstDot?.center = CGPoint.init(x: (firstDot?.center.x)! + translation.x, y: (firstDot?.center.y)! + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}

func drawBlueCircle(){
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 60, y: 60, width: 30, height: 30), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    firstDotView?.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **target** for your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is *wrong*.

```
let firstDotPanRecgnzr = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(firstDotHandler(sender:)))
```

target tells the pan gesture where your selector is located. I think you confused it to be which element it is supposed to act on. (I made the same mistake when i was new :D)

---

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624211-init).

> **target**
>
> An object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the
>   receiver when it recognizes a gesture. nil is not a valid value.

Comment: you are correct. thank you. if you don't mind. i am noticing that i do not have to touch on my blue circle to drag it around.  I am able to drag the circle even if i am touching quite far away from it. please could you advise?

Comment: @babylon which is the blue circle? You could add the pan gesture to it. Also check if use interaction is enabled for the said view.

Comment: the blue circle is drawn in the layer of the child UIIView (in this case 'firstDotView')

Comment: @babylon this should help if it is a layer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831037/how-to-move-a-layer-by-dragging

Comment: If I have multiple sub-layers in a view, my understanding is that you cannot apply UIPanGestureRecognizers to layers?

Comment: @babylon no as far as i know, they can only be applied to views.

Comment: Downvoter can you leave a comment about the downvote so that if there is a mistake i can fix it and learn?